# Google Plus 21-digit URL Number Relationship to a Google Place's ID and Reference Numbers

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-plus, google-places-api

What is the relationship between a Google Place's ID and Reference Number and the same Place's 21-digit Google Plus number used in the Place's Google Plus URL?

I want to link Google Plus URLs for 100's of different businesses to my website.  However, I do not know the Google Plus URL address for each of the businesses.  But I do know the Google Place ID and Reference Number for each of the businesses.  Can I derive the 21-digit Google Plus Number for a business from their Google Places ID and Reference Number?  If I can, what is the formula that creates the 21-digit Google Plus Number?

Or is the Google Plus number completely random so that there is no relationship at all with the Google Place's ID and Reference Number?

Comment: afaik there is no relationship

Comment: So, aside from querying the Google Places API or getting the info directly from a business (Google Place), are there any other options/lists available to find a business' google plus URL?

Comment: the turks head in dublin for instance is https://plus.google.com/107784120751448980545/about

Comment: Google Places is gone btw, it's now Google Local

Comment: Do you happen to have access to the turks head Google Places ID # and reference # that would verify that the 107784120751448980545 string used in the Google Local URL is not related or formulated from either or both of those numbers?

Comment: So in the example that Rachel gave for turks head in dublin,  https://plus.google.com/107784120751448980545/about

Answer (score 1):

The ID gives you the URL, just prefix it with "https://plus.google.com/" but as far as I know there is no way to get a ref from the ID. The ref is returned by an API search and when you have a valid ref if you want to ask detail ( i.e reviews ) from this ref you must keep it somewhere and it's a pain because it's a very long string. So if somebody knows how to get the ref from a ID that would be great !

Comment: So in the example that Rachel gave for turks head in dublin,  https://plus.google.com/107784120751448980545/about , the string, 107784120751448980545, is actually the ID number for the google place, turks head?  is that correct?  So as long as I know a place's ID number, I can derive the URL by just adding "https://plus.google.com/".  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

### Google's 21-digit number is a *numeric form of your UserID*.

Most Google sites & API's that identify the *`UserID`* in the URL will function properly while interchangeably using any of:

- your "text" UserID (your Gmail address to the left of the `@`),
- your 21-digit numeric UserID (as determined below), or,
- the word `default` in place of either (representing the currently authenticated user).

---

One way to **see *your* numeric UserID** is to — while logged into your Google Account — go to:

[`https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default/`](https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default/)

*The 21-digit page title is your numeric Google UserID.*

---

If you have a **21-digit number that you want to confirm is yours**, go to:

**`https://plus.google.com/` *`_21digitUserID_`***

If it loads your Plus page, that's your numeric Google UserID.  <sub>(Unless you, like me, have deactivated your Google Plus page!)</sub>

---

> ***"Kinda Related" Bonus Tip:***
>   You can insert **`+`** plus signs followed by text **after** your Gmail address — *and* add/remove **`.`** dots **anywhere** in your Gmail address — without a problem.
>
> So, these would all get delivered to the same place:
>
> ```
> abc123@gmail.com       abc123+SortToMySecretFolder@gmail.com       a.b.c.123@gmail.com
> abc123+camping.trip@gmail.com    abc.123@gmail.com   abc123+spam.site.signup@gmail.com
> ```
>
> You could utilize this by creating [*rules*](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en) to handle each address in a different way, or even track which websites are selling your email address to spammers.  <sub>([Source](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html))</sub>