# Google Places API search by URL

Tags: url, geocoding, google-places-api

Suppose I have a Google Plus/Places URL (e.g https://plus.google.com/111840715355681175070/about?hl=en-US)

This is actually the URL for a result via the Google Places API (https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/). The sequence of numbers after plus.google.com doesn't seem to correspond to id, reference or place_id.

Suppose I only knew the URL, is there anyway of mapping this to an id, reference or placeid so I can find it via the Places API?

Once solution seems to dump the URL into the Places Text Search but this is expensive (10x multiplier in terms of rate limiting) and seems silly.

Comment: "This is actually the URL for a result via the Google Places API". Can you post the url of Google places API ?

Comment: No!

See also:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753404/google-plus-21-digit-url-number-relationship-to-a-google-places-id-and-referenc

Answer (score 0):

try this google places api through url

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/